# Morris Chart Redraw issue

Tags: jquery, charts, morris.js

I'm using the Morris Chart but when using the multiple charts, the second chart is not showing its bars.

```
$(function () {
    // Fuel per 100k data //
    var fuel_data = [
     {"period": "2013-01", "city": 66, "highway": 34, "idle": 9},
     {"period": "2013-02", "city": 62, "highway": 33, "idle": 8},
     {"period": "2013-03", "city": 61, "highway": 32, "idle": 7},
     {"period": "2013-04", "city": 66, "highway": 32, "idle": 6},
     {"period": "2013-05", "city": 67, "highway": 31, "idle": 5},
     {"period": "2013-06", "city": 68, "highway": 43, "idle": 7},
     {"period": "2013-07", "city": 62, "highway": 32, "idle": 5},
     {"period": "2013-08", "city": 61, "highway": 32, "idle": 5},
     {"period": "2013-09", "city": 58, "highway": 32, "idle": 7},
     {"period": "2013-10", "city": 60, "highway": 32, "idle": 7},
     {"period": "2013-11", "city": 60, "highway": 32, "idle": 6},
     {"period": "2013-12", "city": 62, "highway": 32, "idle": 8}
    ];
    Morris.Line({
      element: 'fuel-consumption',
      hideHover: 'auto',
      data: fuel_data,
      xkey: 'period',
      xLabels: 'month',
      ykeys: ['city', 'highway', 'idle'],
      postUnits: ' l/100km',
      labels: ['City', 'Highway', 'Idle'],
      resize: true,
      lineColors: ['#A52A2A','#72A0C1','#7BB661']
      //yLabelFormat: function(y) { return y.toString() + ' l/100km'; }
    });
    // / Fuel per 1000k data //
    // Fuel projection //
    Morris.Donut({
      element: 'fuel-projection',
      hideHover: 'auto',
      resize: true,
      data: [
        {label: 'Consumption until today', value: 180 },
        {label: 'Projected consumption', value: 400 },
      ],
      colors: ['#7BB661','#72A0C1'],
      formatter: function (y) { return y + " liters" }
    });
    // / Fuel projection //
    // CO2 Emissons //
    bar = Morris.Bar({
      element: 'co2-emissions',
      resize: true,
      data: [
        {month: 'Jan', emissions: 35},
        {month: 'Feb', emissions: 37},
        {month: 'Mar', emissions: 40},
        {month: 'Apr', emissions: 38},
        {month: 'Maj', emissions: 39},
        {month: 'Jun', emissions: 42},
        {month: 'Jul', emissions: 37},
        {month: 'Aug', emissions: 65},
        {month: 'Sep', emissions: 38},
        {month: 'Okt', emissions: 45},
        {month: 'Nov', emissions: 41},
        {month: 'Dec', emissions: 41}
      ],
      xkey: 'month',
      ykeys: ['emissions'],
      labels: ['Co2 emissions'],
      barRatio: 0.4,
      xLabelAngle: 35,
      hideHover: 'auto',
      postUnits: ' g/km',
      formatter: function (y) { return y + " g/km" }
    });
  });
```

Please help!
[JSFiddle for the Code](http://jsfiddle.net/rbsthlm/cD6dd/2/)

Please check columun the 2 tab

Comment: Brought code into question, edited out fluff, improved formatting.